# Serilog filtering doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore, serilog-expressions

I'm trying to test Serilog filtering with a simple example, but it doesn't seem to read the string I provide correctly.
When I use the "ByExcluding" method it doesn't exclude any logs, and when I use "ByIncludingOnly" it doesn't show any logs, which suggests that it simply doesn't understand what I wrote in the expression.

I have the Serilog.AspNetCore and Serilog.Expressions nuget packages installed.

This is what I tried:

```
using Serilog;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .Filter.ByExcluding("@Level = 'Debug'")
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File("logs/myapp.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Hello, Serilog!");
Log.Warning("This is a warning.");
Log.Debug("This is a debug message.");
Log.Error("This is an error.");
```

It's supposed to print all logs except the "Debug" one, but instead it prints all of them.

Comment: What makes you think `@Level` is a known token/value?
I'd have a read of the README in https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions - the simplest way to play with it is to do `Log.ForContext("abc","123).Information("Message")` and try to concot an expression that works on that